# Python, invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

necesito ayuda, no se porque me da un error en la linea de
 **f_num = int(first_number)**

```
    from tkinter import *

# Funciones
def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

def button_calcular():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    f_num = int(first_number)

    second_number = a.get()
    b.insert(0, f_num * int(second_number))

# Configuración de la raíz
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="lightblue")
root.config(bd=100)
root.title("Calculadora")


e = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 =Button(root, text="2", command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 =Button(root, text="3", command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 =Button(root, text="4", command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 =Button(root, text="5", command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 =Button(root, text="6", command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 =Button(root, text="7", command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 =Button(root, text="8", command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 =Button(root, text="9", command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 =Button(root, text="0", command=lambda: button_click(0))

a = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=5)
a.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

b = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=5)
b.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)

button_calculadora =Button(root, text="Calcular", command=button_calcular())

button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)

button_calculadora.grid(row=8, column=1)

# Finalmente bucle de la apliación
root.mainloop()
```

Ya he añadido todo el código a ver si así resulta más claro a ver cual es el error. Se supone que tengo que un numero con los botones, que me salga en una entry, luego meter un numero con teclado en otra entry, darle al boton de calcular y que en la ultima entry me salgan lo que hay en las dos ultimas entrys multiplicados

El error es este:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: de dónde sacas `e`, has intentado hacer `print(e.get())` y ver qué trae?

Comment: e viene de aquí e = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=5)

Comment: antes de eso tengo otro boton def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

Comment: todo esto es para hacer una especie de calculadora

Comment: puedes editar la pregunta y agregar ese pedazo de código?

Comment: Realice una prueba con el código que pusiste y me funciona, obviamente yo lo complete a mi manera, **Seria bueno que adiciones más codigo en tu pregunta para identificar el error ;)**

Comment: Ahhh bueno el error si no me equivoco es cuando quieres ingresar una cadena vacia en el `Entry`, creo que solo es problema de validación ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada el error se encuentra en la siguiente linea:

```
button_calculadora =Button(root, text="Calcular", command=button_calcular())
```

intenta poniendo de esta forma:

```
button_calculadora =Button(root, text="Calcular", command=button_calcular)
```

Podrias tener el mismo problema por validación cuando ingresas un vacio en tu `Entry` salta ese error, yo sugiero primero que nada validar letras y campos vacio al calcular:

```
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox
def is_valid_char(char):
    return char in "0123456789."

validatecommand = root.register(is_valid_char)
e.configure(validate="key", validatecommand=(validatecommand, "%S"))
```

Y para los vacios:

```
def button_calcular():
    first_number = e.get()
    second_number = a.get()

    if (first_number == '' or second_number == ''):
        MessageBox.showinfo('Error', 'Verifique los campos')
        return

    global f_num
    f_num = int(first_number)
    b.insert(0, f_num * int(second_number))
```

Podrias hacer algo asi.

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Hola! Al probar tu clase de button_calcular me sale este error:                                   NameError: name 'window' is not defined

Comment: Ahh bueno si perdon en tu caso seria root

Comment: Y txt en tu caso seria `e` perdon esque lo realice a mi manera antes de que completes tu codigo

Comment: Vale muchas gracias ya lo he cambiado, aunque ahora me dice                             NameError: name 'MessageBox' is not defined :(

Comment: Debes importarlo `from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox`

Comment: De todas formas revisare el codigo que actualizaste ya que al parecer es otro error

Comment: Bueno al parecer el error estaba al instanciar tu boton para calcular ya actualice la respuesta, espero te funcione ;)

Comment: Me ha servido perfectamente, muchas gracias!